# How to Simulate an Accurate Projectile Motion in Blender

Tags: physics

Is there any way to create an object shooting at an initial velocity that forms an accurate projectile trajectory? I'm referring to something similar to PHeT's 2D cannon experiment--but with Blender. Right now I'm looking to create a trajectory without having to manually add keyframes for points on the trajectory, so, essentially, relying completely on the Physics Features of Blender. The problem is that I don't know a way to make the object move with an initial velocity at a certain angle.

Recently, I've messed around and tried to replicate a simulation from PHeT, and this is the result
[image]

As you can see, I had to add keyframes for the integral parts of the trajectory (which I copied exactly for PhEt's accurate simulation). I tried to minimize the number of keyframes, in a way where the endpoint would still be the same, but it isn't really accurate. The wireframe lines are where the trajectory points are.

However, what I really want to achieve is a projectile trajectory without animated/manual keyframes. Is there any way to achieve this, or at least get somewhere close to it? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: do you mean that you want to generate keyframes, or simply want to have the good physics trajectory?

Comment: I want to generate keyframes of an accurate physics trajectory only using (if possible) blender features without manually adding them for each point on the curve--if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Just keyframe animation of two locations (e.g. 0/0/0 at frame 1, and 0/4/4 at frame 5).
Then keyframe "animated" checked of that rigid body object for frame 5, and keyframe "animated" unchecked for frame 6.

then you get:

[image]

and if you add a wind force (force field) you get:

[image]

Comment: Maybe useful information for anybody who wants to do something similar - let'S say the last keyframe for the movement of the rigid body object is on frame $n$, than the keyframe $x$ to uncheck _Animated_ has to be $4\leq x\leq(n+1)$, so the "uncheck keyframe" $x$ can never be earlier than frame 4 and never be later than 1 frame after the movement is keyframed, otherwise this will not work.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann very interesting. Of course as I understand it, the "keyframe $n$" is a simplification and you mean the last frame with desired movement - which can be after extrapolated fcurve value past the last keyframe, or an fcurve modifier or a driver… Also any idea why the $≥ 4$? It's as if not only velocity ($>2$), but also acceleration had to be evaluated… Does the requirement stand if you start animating before frame $1$?

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful, I'll look into it

Comment: Hi Andrewy, if my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer, thx.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Yes, keyframe $n$ is a simplification regarding the above question, where no modifiers are used since it showed a simple way to give the rigid body an initial velocity. Don't know where that velocity > 2 is from, that's not necessary to make the simulation take over from the animation (it's just when gravity is enabled you need some velocity as soon as physics take over). But the $\geq 4$ was a simplification according to the answer, too - actually it has to be _Simulation Start_ + 3. But since these things are not in the answer and it is not mine, I did not go into detail.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann still, I wonder why it's the simulation start $+3$… I imagine it could be $+1$, because, then it can read the previous position, current position, and based on it calculate the offset between the two as velocity and apply that to the rigid body. But perhaps it can't use current frame, as it is being evaluated, therefore it needs $+2$ to have two previous frames to get the velocity. So I wonder why it needs one more frame, as if it needed to also calculate acceleration for some reason, but that wouldn't make sense to me.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Maybe the velocities are calculated after physics simulation, and therefore this velocity value "lags" 1 frame behind and that's the reason? 

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I have no idea why it works as it does, and could only give wild speculations here in the comments :D By the way, if $m$ is start of movement, then my earlier condition is $(m+2)\leq x\leq (n+1)$. My last guess on this topic: you are probably correct, it cannot use the current frame, so it needs $(x-2, x-1)$ to calculate velocity and direction on $x$. And the extra frame is probably needed because, as you suggested, physics are calculated before the velocity. But I don't know. I just use that conditioning to make sure initial movement is considered in simulations.